# Emacs: Launch Emacs with init.el in Dropbox directory

Tags: emacs, ubuntu-13.10

I have my `init.el` stored here: `~/Dropbox/workspaces/emacs/.emacs.d/init.el` but when I launch emacs (ie by entering `emacs` in the terminal), I only get the default emacs. I tried to set up a ".desktop" file, shown below, but it has no effect.

When I run `/usr/bin/emacs24 %F -q --load /home/lucas/Dropbox/workspaces/emacs/.emacs.d/init.el` from the terminal, my `init.el` loads properly.

How can I launch emacs easily and get my `init.el` to load from my Dropbox location? I am running Ubuntu 13.10 (I tried asking this on AskUbuntu, but no responses).

```
lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-T420:~$ whereis emacs24
emacs24: /usr/bin/emacs24 /etc/emacs24 /usr/bin/X11/emacs24 /usr/share/emacs24 /usr/share/man/man1/emacs24.1.gz

lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-T420:~$ cat .local/applications/emacs24.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=GNU Emacs 24
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=View and edit files
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
Exec=/usr/bin/emacs24 %F -q --load /home/lucas/Dropbox/workspaces/emacs/.emacs.d/init.el
TryExec=emacs24
Icon=emacs24
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;Development;TextEditor;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Place a dummy init file into your $HOME directory, as `~/.emacs` with the following contents:

```
(setq user-emacs-directory (expand-file-name "~/Dropbox/workspaces/emacs/.emacs.d/"))
(load (locate-user-emacs-file "init.el"))
```

That will not only load your configuration from Dropbox, but also make various Emacs packages save their caches and histories to your Dropbox.  For instance, if you are using savehist, you'll have your minibuffer history shared via Dropbox.

Comment: If you're on Windows, you'll need to add a HOME environment for tilde expansion to work (e.g. I set HOME to "C:\Users\David.Sharpe"). After doing that, don't forget that the "dummy" init file needs to be put inside your new home directory, not in "AppData\Roaming" or wherever it used to be. Alternatively, you could just set HOME to be your Dropbox directory, but I prefer it to be my User home.

Answer (score 1):

When I build Emacs from source, my next step is to create a file called `site-start.el` and I place it in the `lisp` directory of the newly built Emacs -- e.g., `.../lisp/site-start.el` -- the contents of your `site-start.el` file will be this:

```
(load-file "/home/lucas/Dropbox/workspaces/emacs/.emacs.d/init.el")
```

If you are using a build of Emacs that already has a `site-start.el`, then just add the above code to the bottom of that file.

Comment: This almost worked, but I got the following error upon loading an ".el" file from Dropbox : `Eager macro-expansion failure: (error "Autoloading failed to define function defadvice")
Cannot open load file: advice
` - For some reason, the answer selected above works.